# Crystal Reports "Load Report failed" Near End of Day

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am getting a "load report failed" when using Crystal Reports on my ASP.NET / VB.NET site. This only occurs near end of day, so it does work normally and as expected throughout the day otherwise. Is there some sort of limit being reached? Here is my code below:

```
        Dim ReportData As System.Data.DataSet = SWS.GetItemsByDateReport(storeID, dateStart, dateEnd, errorStr)

        Dim reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("Reports/ItemsByDate.rpt")
        Dim pdfFilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/temp/")

        Me.reportDoc = New ReportDocument()
        Me.reportDoc.Load(reportPath)

        Me.reportDoc.SetDataSource(ReportData.Tables(0))
        Me.reportDoc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdfFilePath & "ItemsByDateReport.pdf")

        'Open report in new window/tab
        Dim s As String = "window.open('temp/ItemsByDateReport.pdf', '_blank');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", s, True)

        reportDoc.Close()
        reportDoc.Dispose()
```